# Binding a nested list in a datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, class, datagrid

I am trying to create a datagrid with all the days of a month and using the categories as the header of each row, I need to fill each cell depending on the day with a value that will be between 0 or the total paid for that day

```
public class CATEGORIES
{ 
     public int IdCat { get; set; }
     public string NameCat { get; set; }
}
public class PAYMENTS
{
     public int IdPay { get; set; }
     public int IdCat { get; set; }
     public double Total { get; set; }
     public DateTime DatePay { get; set; }
}
```

I have thought of creating a new class having an object of type Categories and a list of objects of type Payments, because I could not create 30 objects of type payments and make them binding in the datagrid, well I could but I think there will be an easier way to do it , also in wpf it does not let me iterate from cell to cell to fill the data programmatically
So I ask for help from this great community of programmers to solve this problem and thank you very much

Comment: Just create a datatable a bind it to the datagrid, then all the changes you do to the databale programatically will reflect on the datagrid, and vice versa

Comment: Okay but how can I make the  first column be fixed like the header of the datagrid?